# libGdx Array removal causes texture to flicker

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx, textures, flicker

I have my camera scrolling along the x-axis and when my floor object goes off screen I add a new floor object beyond the screen boundaries and remove the old one that has left the view.

When and only when I remove the object it causes my other objects in that Array to flicker

here is the code with the removal commented out.

```
batch.begin()

for(GameObject pillar: pillars) {
    pillar.draw(batch);     
    if(pillar.getBounds().getX() + 64 < camera.position.x - SCREEN_WIDTH/2) {
        //pillars.removeValue(pillar, false);
    }
}

batch.end()
```

and here is another example where I am also adding to the Array

```
for(GameObject ceiling: ceilings) {
    ceiling.draw(batch, SCREEN_WIDTH, CEILING_HEIGHT);
    if((ceiling.getBounds().getX() + ceiling.getBounds().getWidth()) < (camera.position.x - SCREEN_WIDTH/2)) {
        ceilings.add(new GameObject(boundsTexture, ceiling.getBounds().getX() + (ceiling.getBounds().getWidth()*2),SCREEN_HEIGHT - CEILING_HEIGHT, false));
        //ceilings.removeValue(ceiling, false);
    }
}
```

this is the GameObject class

```
public class GameObject {
protected Vector2 location;
private Rectangle bounds;
protected Texture frame;
protected TextureRegion currentFrame;

GameObject(Texture texture, float xLocation, float yLocation, boolean flippedV) {
    frame = texture;
    location = new Vector2(xLocation, yLocation);
    bounds = new Rectangle( location.x, location.y,
                            frame.getWidth(),
                            frame.getHeight());

    currentFrame = new TextureRegion(frame, 0, 0, 64, 64);
    if(flippedV) {
        currentFrame.flip(false, true);
    }
}
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
    batch.draw(currentFrame, location.x, location.y);
}
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float width, float height) {
    batch.draw(currentFrame, location.x, location.y, width, height);
}
public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return bounds;
}
```

}

I should mention I am using deltaTime to move the camera, nothing else moves,
the camera is Orthographic.

```
camera.translate(300*delta,0);
```

I also tried

```
camera.translate((int)300*delta,0);
```

Comment: I fixed it, I took the code that adds and removes out of the...

    batch.begin();
    batch.end();

Comment: Post your fix as answer to your question here.. this will help others with similar problem.. thanks

Comment: I did this but I cannot accept the answer for 2 days

Comment: thank you for posting answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the add and remove code from the SpriteBatch

```
batch.begin()
//remove the code that adds and removes from the Array
batch.end();
//put that code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not remove value from List while you iterate through it. Try saving the objects you want to remove in another list and when for loop finishes then remove them from the pillars list.

You can also try doing it with Iterator.

Comment: So I should create a second Array/List to add/reference the objects I want to remove and then iterate through that list and remove those objects from the original list, I think I understand it. thanks.

Comment: Yes for example you can save the index where the object is and then remove it by index